# Enviar 2 modelos al return del View asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

En 2 modelos diferentes tengo un metodo que me devuelve una lista cada uno

```
Lista<Categorias>------------------Lista<Rutas>
```

Estoy pasando uno usando lo siguiente en el `ActionResult` de la vista

```
public ActionResult Categoria()
{
   return View(ct.listar());
}
```

Como hago para enviar el `rt.lista()`(El de la rutas), junto al de categorias al return del `View` de forma correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi creando un clase con los siguiente datos:

```
public class vmRutasCate
{
    public List<categoria> cate { get; set; }
    public List<rutas> rut { get; set; }

}
```

y en el `ActionResult` asigne los datos a un objeto y se lo envie al `View`

```
public ActionResult Categoria()
{
    public vmRutasCate modelEnlace = new vmRutasCate();
    modelEnlace.cate = ct.listar();
    modelEnlace.rut = rt.listarRutas();
    return View(modelEnlace);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo utilizaría el `viewBag` en vez de hacer clases para cada vez que quieres devolver mas de un tipo de dato, el `viewBag` se utiliza para esto, pasar variables dinámicas.

Asi se asignan variables al `viewBag`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.listaCaterogias = miListaCategorias;
    ViewBag.listaRutas= miListaRutas;

    return View();
}
```

Y en la vista para recogerlas

```
@ViewBag.listaCaterogias 
@ViewBag.listaRutas
```

[ControllerBase.ViewBag Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx)